# Clean Installation of Ubuntu Without IP KVM

Tags: ssh

I don't have access to an IP KVM but was hoping to do have the ability to do a fresh install without only SSH keys installed in order to remotely run and compile code while I'm away from home. Is there any way to have ubuntu clean reinstall with just the ssh keys installed after a simple restart without any user input?

Comment: AFAIK the Ubuntu installer supports cloud-init for customisations and scripting (post) installation tasks, including the creation of users and deploying public ssh keys in their newly created home directory  `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` . https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall - https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.8/topics/examples.html?highlight=ssh-authorized-keys